# Overriding Flask add_url_rule to route a specific URL

Tags: python, view, flask, django-class-based-views

I'm using the class-based views in Flask for creating a CRUD REST API and registering the routes using `add_url_rule` like so...

```
class GenericAPI(MethodView):
    def get(self, item_group, item_id):
        ...
    def post(self, item_group, item_id):
        ...
    ...

api_view = GenericAPI.as_view('apps_api')
app.add_url_rule('/api/<item_group>', defaults={'item_id': None},
                 view_func=api_view, methods=['GET',])
app.add_url_rule('/api/<item_group>/<item_id>', 
                 view_func=api_view, methods=['GET',])
app.add_url_rule('/api/<item_group>/add', 
                 view_func=api_view, methods=['POST',])
app.add_url_rule('/api/<item_group>/<item_id>/edit', 
                 view_func=api_view, methods=['PUT',])
app.add_url_rule('/api/<item_group>/<item_id>/delete', 
                 view_func=api_view, methods=['DELETE',])
```

It handles specific database tables based on `item_group` and entries using `item_id`. So if I have `/api/person`, it will list entries for the person table. Or if I have `/api/equipment/2`, it will retrieve the row with ID 2 in the equipment table. I have alot of these tasks and they all basically need CRUD only.

But what if I want to override my routing when I have some other URL like `/api/analysis/summarize` which theoretically would call to a function that does the on-the-fly work. Is there a way to do that?

Or is the only way extend my URLs to `/api/db/person` and `/api/db/equipment/2` for one set of actions and `/api/other_work_type` for others?

Comment: I reread the documentation and saw that you can pass values using `defaults`. So what I ended up doing was instead of `app.add_url_rule('/api/<item_group>/<item_id>', view_func=api_view, methods=['GET',])` I changed it to `app.add_url_rule('/api/person/<item_id>', view_func=api_view, methods=['GET',])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register `/api/analysis/summarize` normally. Werkzeug/Flask sorts the rules by complexity (amount of variables), taking the simplest routes first.

E.g.:

```
@app.route('/api/foo')
def foo():
    return "Foo is special!"

@app.route('/api/<name>')
def generic(name):
    return "Hello %s!" % name
```

Independent of the order you define the routes in.