# Two route handlers get called

Tags: flask, routes

I have a simple Flask app which has two routes configured:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.route("/api/v1/foo")(api.bar)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<path:path>')
def view(path=None):
    print 'BAZ'
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`api.bar` is defined as

```
def bar():
    return "BAR";
```

Now, running locally, and visiting `http://localhost/api/v1/foo` I will get the response I expect (just text `BAR`), but looking at the console, I see that `BAZ` was printed as well.

Shouldn't just the first matched route trigger? Or if this is expected, is there a way to specify the behaviour I need?

Comment: It always does what defined later..

Comment: Actually, the order doesn't matter. I just tested it, and whatever the order is, I get the response defined with '/api/v1/foo', but other view also gets executed.

Comment: According to flask docs, `path` behaves exactly like `string` with one difference - it accepts slashes. In your situation (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17759563/overriding-flask-add-url-rule-to-route-a-specific-url) `Werkzeug/Flask sorts the rules by complexity (amount of variables), taking the simplest routes first. Independent of the order you define the routes in.` it should print only `BAR`. Please attach your logs.